# PL/SQL Oracle Query With IF Statement

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, plsql, oracle-apex

I want to implement a query that only returns the logged in user and displays there record only, which I have done as follows and it works:

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE UPPER(username) = v('APP_USER')
```

However, I have another column called User_Type, and a user can be type 1, 2 or 3. If I have a user type of 1, I want the query to also return all the tables records too as user type 1 is an admin.

I thought about doing it like this:

```
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM Employee 
WHERE upper(username) = v('APP_USER')
IF User_Type = 1
THEN SELECT * FROM Employee
END IF;
END;
/
```

But it doesn't work in APEX Oracle PLSQL.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

From what I understand you need to try this:

```
DECLARE
  emp employee%ROWTYPE; -- Create a record type
  tbl_emp IS TABLE OF emp;
  -- ^^^ Create a table of that record type
  v_user_type employee.user_type%TYPE;
  -- ^^^ Variable to store user type
BEGIN
  SELECT user_type
    INTO v_user_type
    FROM Employee 
   WHERE upper(username) = v('APP_USER');

  IF v_user_type = 1 THEN
    SELECT *
           BULK COLLECT INTO tbl_emp
      FROM employee;
    -- ^^ Returns the entire table
  ELSE
    SELECT *
           BULK COLLECT INTO tbl_emp
      FROM employee;
     WHERE upper(username) = v('APP_USER');
    -- ^^ Returns the row related to the user.
  END IF;
END;
/
```

The output is stored in the nested table variable `tbl_emp`.

**EDIT:**

It can be achieved using pure SQL also, like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM employee e
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM employees e_in
                WHERE e_in.user_type = 1
                  AND UPPER(e_in.username) = v('APP_USER'))
    OR UPPER(e.username) = v('APP_USER')
```

Choose whichever is best suited for you.

Answer (score 2):

You want all records from users with either `UPPER(username)` being `v('APP_USER')` or `User_Type` being 1? Then just use `OR`:

```
SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE upper(username) = v('APP_USER') OR User_Type = 1
```

If that's not what you mean, then can you explain more clearly?

Comment: when doing just with app_user, only return that username records, unless that user has a '1' user type then return the whole table.

Comment: I don't understand. There could be many records satisfying `upper(username) = v('APP_USER')`?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select distinct e2.*
from employee e1
join employee e2 on (e1.username = e2.username or e1.User_Type = 1)
where UPPER(e1.username) = v('APP_USER')
```

Comment: Very understandable and compact but I'm just a little concerned about the performance as I'm a big `distinct`phobic. Can you please explain the performance impacts?

Comment: The `distinct` is included on the chance that more than one employee record satisfies the `UPPER(e1.username) = v('APP_USER')` condition - if that will never happen then the `distinct` can be removed. It would probably have a significant performance impact when querying against a reasonably large table - say, several hundred thousand records - but employee tables are usually relatively small, so the performance impact is likely to be relatively small.